# Poisson Regression and Hessian

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, poisson-regression, hessian

I have been trying to estimate parameters of a poisson regression. I am using Newton Raphson method. This method requires that the inverse of Hessian be computed to obtain, updates to beta vector. The text book that I am using defines the Hessian as 
$$-\sum x'_{i}xe^{x'_i\beta}$$
This doesn't seem to be a $p \times p$ matrix. Here $X$ is $n \times p$ design matrix and $e^{x_i\beta}$ is the mean function and when evaluated it will be a $n \times 1$ vector.

The hessian according to this definition seems to be $n \times 1$ vector. How can we then compute inverse of this vector? What is the correct formula for Hessian?

Comment: You *do not* have to compute the inverse of the hessian.  Instead, you need to solve a system of linear equations in which the hessian appears!

Answer (score 5):

Based on the notation "$x_i' \beta$" I can infer that $x_i$ is a $p \times 1$ **column** vector such that $x_i'$ is the $i$th row of the design matrix $X$.
Then I suspect the authors meant
$$- \sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{x_i' \beta} x_i x_i'.$$
Since $x_i x_i'$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, the dimensions make sense.

---

You can check that this is the same as
$$-X' W X = - \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \\ \end{bmatrix}_{p\times n} \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{x_1'\beta} & & 0 \\ & \ddots \\ 0& & e^{x_n'\beta}
\end{bmatrix}_{n\times n} \
\begin{bmatrix} x_1'\\ x'_2 \\ \vdots \\x_n' \end{bmatrix}_{n\times p}$$
from your answer. (Note that you forgot a minus sign.)

Comment: I think the negative sign is correct if you are taking the Hessian of the log-likelihood function (which you would maximize). However, if you were instead minimizing the negative log-likelihood (as common in some fields) then the sign would be flipped.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the correct formulation of Hessian in poisson regression. The hessian is defined as $H= - X^TWX$, here $X$ is the $n \times p$ design matrix and $W$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix where diagonal entries are the $e^{x'_i\beta}$.
Hessian has to be a square matrix as its inverse is used in parameter updates and also used for computing the covariance matrix.